# Infer correct argument types with the default value

Tags: typescript, inference

I have an object with "query handlers", each query handler can receive an object with "arguments" using destructuring and I need specify the argument type with the default value.

```js
class BaseArg<T> {
  value: T;
}
class NumberArg extends BaseArg<number> {}
class BooleanArg extends BaseArg<boolean> {}

type QueryArgs = { [key: string]: BaseArg<any> };
type Query = (args?: QueryArgs) => any;
type Queries = { [query: string]: Query };

class User {
  id: number;
  isAvailable: boolean;
}

const users: User[] = [];

const queries: Queries = {
  getUser: ({
    id = new NumberArg(), // <- this is "BaseArg<any>" but I expect "NumberArg"
  }) => {
    return users.find(user => user.id === id.value);
  },
  getUsers: ({
    onlyAvailables = new BooleanArg(), // <- this is BaseArg<any> but I expect BooleanArg
  }) => {
    if(onlyAvailables) {
      return users.filter(user => user.isAvailable);
    }
    return users;
  },
};
```

In the `QueryArgs` I use the `BaseArg<any>` as values, but it has the default value as `NumberArg` and `BooleanArg`, how can do it without specify the query args type

```js
  getUser: ({
    id = new NumberArg(),
  }: {
    id: NumberArg,
  }) => {
    return users.find(user => user.id === id.value);
  },
```

Comment: If I do not specify the type of main object, the argument will be correct `const queries = {...` but I need add the type for make better declarations

Comment: I discovered that if I set the "QueryArgs" type to "unknown," the type is inferred correctly, but now the accessories can be anything.

does anyone have an idea how to accept only "extend BaseArg"?